# Surjections to free commutative dgas

Tags: homological-algebra, differential-graded-algebras

Consider the category $C$ of commutative dgas (unbounded in both degrees) over a ring $R$ 
(in practice the integers or the integers mod $p$).

Let $F$ be the free functor from chain complexes to $C$ and 
let $D^n$ be the chain complex of $R$ in degrees $n$ and $n-1$
with non-trivial differential the identity.

Does anyone know if there is a commutative dga $A^n$
which admits a surjection $A^n \to F(D^n)$ and whose 
unit map $R \to A^n$ is a quasi-isomorphism?

Comment: Over a ring containing the rationals, yes. You can take a factorization of the unit of the free algebra in the model category of CDGAs as a trivial cofibration followed by a fibration. This is not your case of interest but well... in case someone else wonders...